# Cannot change password as user in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I have an issue while changing password as a user and I cannot find anything in documentation metioning changing password as a user without admin priviliges.

I am logged as user `abc` and I execute:

`set password for "abc" = 'abc'`

I receive:
`ERR: error authorizing query: abc not authorized to execute statement 'SET PASSWORD FOR abc = [REDACTED]', requires admin privilege`

Is it possible to change password as a user not as admin?

Answer (score 3):

That is true, it should not be done by the standard user. You are able to change your password, you should not be able to change other's password if no admin privileges set.

Let say there is `testuser` standard user with no admin privileges and another user named `admin` with admin privileges.

if you login with admin then you should be able to change anyone's password with CLI:

`set password for "testuser" = 'testing'`

logging with `testuser` and changing admins password will through en error of course:

`set password for "admin" = 'adminpass'`

response:

`ERR: error authorizing query: testuser not authorized to execute statement 'SET PASSWORD FOR admin = [REDACTED]', requires admin privilege`

even if you run `show users` with testuser, it will not let you see other users and it is admin privileges.

`ERR: error authorizing query: testuser not authorized to execute statement 'SHOW USERS', requires admin privilege`

Solution for changing anyone's password:

`CREATE USER "someuser" WITH PASSWORD 'somepassword' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES`

but it requires admin privileges.